# Youtube Data API get oldest videos from a channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I successfully get the most recent videos from a youtube channel by using `order=date`, i now want to get the oldest videos due to youtube api not returning pages after 500 results.    Is there a parameter than can accomplish this?

```
     $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?
key='.$api_key.'&channelId='.$channel_id.'&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults='.$limit.'&fields=*');

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented way to order by reverse date order. see;

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

YouTube offers a 500 limit on returned items, so unfortunately the only way you can do this is page through the 500 results and order them within your application.

If you want to recieve the max number of videos possible you could make a API call with every concievable order value so 'order' with 'date','rating', 'relevence','title','videoCount','viewCount' then strip out any duplicates. Of course only applicable to channels > 500 videos, you could make an additional API request to get the 'videoCount' before doing this and break out of the operation if the number of unique videos is equal to the 'videoCount' value. Its messy and not guaranteed to pull all results, but the only way to do this given the current API.